# How to read enum from maven pom plugin configuration?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a maven plugin which I want to have the following config:

```
<ObjectName>
  <ObjectType>
    <Param1>12</Param1>
    <EnumTypeParam>4</EnumTypeParam>
  </ObjectType>
</objectName>
```

Where EnumTypeParam is a java enumeration. how would I do this in the pom file?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm trying to get your maven protoc plugin working with the language specs however it won't accept `<language>JAVA</language>` in the pom.xml file.

Comment: I updated the question with the section of my pom file which I used to get it working.

Comment: Please supply your solution as an answer.

Answer (score -2):

I ended up using something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-protoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
        <protocExecutable>protoc</protocExecutable>
        <protoSourceRoot>${project.basedir}/target/protobuff/speed</protoSourceRoot>
                <languageSpecifications>
                    <LanguageSpecification>
                        <language>JAVA</language>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                    </LanguageSpecification>
                    <LanguageSpecification>
                        <language>CPP</language>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/cpp</outputDirectory>
                    </LanguageSpecification>
                </languageSpecifications>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```